# What does the "bedding" symbolize in the Hailsham description in "Never Let Me Go"?

Tags: symbolism, never-let-me-go, kazuo-ishiguro

In the exposition of the story, the transformations of the characters as they enter to the adulthood is given in the chapter ten and the reminisces they make are central to the whole story of having babies and how they were not allowed etc, in that what does "the mountain of bedding" symbolize :
it felt like a mountain of
bedding was pounding at you, so that half the time you weren't sure if you
were doing it with the boy or all that stuff."